# Having issues with a Pop and a Hiss

Tags: mixer, lavalier, snap-crackle-pop

I put this video together to help demonstrate my problem:

I forgot to mention in the video, but my entire rig runs through a Monster Pro Power 2500.

Comment: Can you add a description of the problem so that there is more details available if the video link ever goes dead please.  Thank you for the effort of demonstrating the problem though.

Comment: @AJ Henderson, I voted to migrate this question to Video because it has very little (or nothing) to do with sound design. But I'll leave it to other moderators to manage.

Comment: If I heard what I think you heard, it sounds to me like cell phone interference.  Perhaps your AT system is picking up on your cell where your other mics don't?

Answer (score 1):

Does the sound go away when you mute your problem mic?

Here are some things I would try:

If it goes away when muted, it is likely RF interference so please move your receiver away from speakers and radios.  You can also adjust the squelch level on your microphone to reduce RF levels when not in use.

If it doesn't go away when muted, please try another frequency on your microphone; if you are around the 800MHz range, try to go near the 550MHz range.  HDTV and other sources can interfere with wireless microphone signals.

It sounds digital to me but it could be from your mics being too close or different sources accidentally sharing the same channel frequency.  If all else fails try a different wireless mic.

Comment: Yes, the sound goes away when I mute the mid... However, the mic is WIRED, its not wireless... so there is no RF receiver.

Comment: Apologies.  The same interference could affect any condenser mic, though.  If you have tried a different outlet, a different cable, a different spot in the room, turning off your phone, and powering your mics with both battery and phantom power separately, then it might just be better to resolve the headache by trying new mics.  I totally believe you that your other mics have worked fine, though.

Comment: Tried all that... didn't make a difference.